# I cannot use Django

Tags: python, django

I want to use Django. I installed it but after that I wanted to create file and I  got this error.

```
django-admin.exe startproject mysite .
django-admin.exe : The term 'django-admin.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path wa
s included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:2
+  django-admin.exe startproject mysite .
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (django-admin.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

what is the problem?

Comment: If django is installing correctly you should see `django-admin.exe` in the `bin` folder where you installed Python. If the exe is there but cmd can't find it, you need to add the `bin` folder to your PATH.

Comment: Hı thank you for editing question. I couldn't find the django-admin.exe and I installed by cmd.